# webcam - where is it?

Tags: webcam, thinkpad

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 on Think pad X230i (Intel® Core™ i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4).

There is a built-in webcam that was active during the installation process but know I don't find it. Actually, I did not find it in the Systemm Settings.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Did you install a webcam like cheese to test the webcam first?

Comment: In which program did you try to access the camera?

Comment: Or try skype to see if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

It is there. Only thing is, You don’t have any app which is using it. Install any Voip you ll see its working.
Or You can try

```
lspci
```

This command will give detailed picture of your hardware which was installed.